# after rotating image on matlab..then results go on bad:(

Tags: matlab

I am intersted with determining branchpoints of retinal images and then registering these images. First of all I am using a algorithm for extracting of vessels from image then skeletization and finding branchpoints. At first operation all things were ok but if I rotate same image by randomize angle, number of branchpoints are very increase. what are your opinions about this problem...

related links of images :
http://e1204.hizliresim.com/w/6/449m6.jpg
http://e1204.hizliresim.com/w/6/449by.jpg

Comment: It's hard to say anything without some examples. Have you tried different methods for `imrotate` function? All the same?

Comment: how can I upload image or files to my question?

Comment: You can edit your question in the links below it. Above the text box there is a button to add an image.

Comment: http://c1204.hizliresim.com/w/5/448x6.jpg
http://c1204.hizliresim.com/w/5/448ys.jpg

Comment: http://c1204.hizliresim.com/w/5/44903.jpg

Comment: http://e1204.hizliresim.com/w/6/449by.jpg

Comment: http://e1204.hizliresim.com/w/6/449m6.jpg

Answer (score 3):

`imrotate`'s standard interpolation algorithm is nearest neighbor, that tends to transform your image in a beautiful saw.

If you rotate your image with `imrotate`, try passing as the third parameter a better method, like bicubic or bilinear, both will be much better.

The syntax is simple:

```
imrotate(img, degrees, 'bicubic');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but results are same. I want to show images, how can I upload these to here?

Comment: if the results are the same, chances are you have to rethink the way you're doing things: rotating after the skeletonization is really necessary? If you rotated the image before, and just then skeletonized it, you wouldn't have to deal with this problem

Comment: I added some images. Please, is there anybody evaluate them.